# How to properly call CFBinaryHeapGetValues() and parse the resulting C Array in Swift?

Tags: arrays, swift, core-foundation, binary-heap

Can anybody please shed some light on how to invoke CFBinaryHeapGetValues on Core Foundation's CFBinaryHeap data structure in Swift? A code sample/example would help me a great deal. This is the code I have currently:

```
public class CountedColor : NSObject
{
    public private(set) var count: Int
    public private(set) var color: UIColor

    public init(color: UIColor, colorCount: Int)
    {
        self.count = colorCount
        self.color = color
        super.init()
    }
}

var callbacks = CFBinaryHeapCallBacks()

callbacks.compare = { (a,b,unused) in
    let afoo : CountedColor = (a?.assumingMemoryBound(to: CountedColor.self).pointee)!
    let bfoo : CountedColor = (b?.assumingMemoryBound(to: CountedColor.self).pointee)!

    if ( afoo.count == bfoo.count ) { return CFComparisonResult.compareEqualTo }
    if ( afoo.count > bfoo.count ) { return CFComparisonResult.compareGreaterThan }
    return CFComparisonResult.compareLessThan
}

let callbackPointer = UnsafeMutablePointer<CFBinaryHeapCallBacks>.allocate(capacity: 1)
callbackPointer.initialize(to: callbacks)
var bh = CFBinaryHeapCreate(nil, 0, callbackPointer, nil)

var fooPointer : UnsafeMutablePointer<CountedColor>!
fooPointer = UnsafeMutablePointer<CountedColor>.allocate(capacity: 1)
fooPointer.initialize(to: CountedColor(color: UIColor.blue, colorCount: 72))
CFBinaryHeapAddValue(bh, fooPointer)
fooPointer = UnsafeMutablePointer<CountedColor>.allocate(capacity: 1)
fooPointer.initialize(to: CountedColor(color: UIColor.red, colorCount: 99))
CFBinaryHeapAddValue(bh, fooPointer)

var elements = [CountedColor](repeating: CountedColor(color: UIColor.white, colorCount: 0), count: 2)
var elementPtr = UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeRawPointer?>.allocate(capacity: 1)
elementPtr.initialize(to: elements)
CFBinaryHeapGetValues(bh, elementPtr)

var returnedValues: UnsafePointer<[CountedColor]> = (elementPtr.pointee?.assumingMemoryBound(to: [CountedColor].self))!
print(elementPtr.pointee?.assumingMemoryBound(to: CountedColor.self).pointee.count)
print(elementPtr.pointee?.assumingMemoryBound(to: CountedColor.self).pointee.color)
let values = returnedValues.pointee
```

^^If you look above at the last three lines the code fails at the last line where I get a EXC_BAD_ACCESS. I am confused why because the above two print statements actually work. I am able to verify that the first object in the C array returned by the function is indeed the smaller color with a count of 72. So this means the array I pass in is being updated with values, however when I try to get a handle on the array by accessing pointee things go haywire. At first I thought it was a memory management thing but after reading how bridging works in Swift I am not sure that is the case especially since this is an annotated CoreFoundation API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code:

```
CFBinaryHeapAddValue(bh, fooPointer)
```

You are passing an `UnsafeMutablePointer<CountedColor>`, two times.

(The number of elements affect many parts.)

So, when calling `CFBinaryHeapGetValues(bh, elementPtr)`, you need to reserve a region for **C-array** which can contain two `UnsafeMutablePointer<CountedColor>`s.

You should write it as:

```
var elementPtr = UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeRawPointer?>.allocate(capacity: 2)  //<- You need to allocate a region for two elements
elementPtr.initialize(to: nil, count: 2) //<- The content is overwritten, initial values can be nil
CFBinaryHeapGetValues(bh, elementPtr)
```

And this code:

```
var returnedValues: UnsafePointer<[CountedColor]> = (elementPtr.pointee?.assumingMemoryBound(to: [CountedColor].self))!
```

As I wrote above, the result stored in the region pointed by `elementPtr` are `UnsafeMutablePointer<CountedColor>`s, not an `UnsafePointer<[CountedColor]>`.

`elementPtr.pointee` retrieves the first `UnsafeMutablePointer<CountedColor>`, so your two `print` statements work, but that does not mean `returnedValues` of your code is holding something you expect.

One good way to handle C-arrays is creating an `UnsafeBufferPointer`.

```
let returnedValues = UnsafeBufferPointer(start: elementPtr, count: 2)
```

`UnsafeBufferPointer` works as a Collection type, so you can easily convert it to an `Array`.

```
let values = returnedValues.map{$0!.load(as: CountedColor.self)}
```

---

And please do not forget to `deinitialize` and `deallocate` the `allocate`ed regions.

To make it, you need to keep all the allocated pointers and their counts. So, you may need to change some part of your code as:

```
var fooPointer : UnsafeMutablePointer<CountedColor>!
fooPointer = UnsafeMutablePointer<CountedColor>.allocate(capacity: 1)
fooPointer.initialize(to: CountedColor(color: UIColor.blue, colorCount: 72))
CFBinaryHeapAddValue(bh, fooPointer)
var barPointer : UnsafeMutablePointer<CountedColor>!
barPointer = UnsafeMutablePointer<CountedColor>.allocate(capacity: 1)
barPointer.initialize(to: CountedColor(color: UIColor.red, colorCount: 99))
CFBinaryHeapAddValue(bh, barPointer)
```

Then after finished using your CFBinaryHeap (`bh`)...

```
elementPtr.deinitialize(count: 2)
elementPtr.deallocate(capacity: 2)
barPointer.deinitialize()
barPointer.deallocate(capacity: 1)
fooPointer.deinitialize()
fooPointer.deallocate(capacity: 1)
```

---

You may want to add arbitrary number of `CountedColor`s to the CFBinaryHeap, in that case, you can write something like this:

```
let colors = [
    CountedColor(color: UIColor.blue, colorCount: 72),
    CountedColor(color: UIColor.red, colorCount: 99),
    //...
]
var fooPointer : UnsafeMutablePointer<CountedColor>!
fooPointer = UnsafeMutablePointer<CountedColor>.allocate(capacity: colors.count)
fooPointer.initialize(from: colors)
for i in colors.indices {
    CFBinaryHeapAddValue(bh, fooPointer+i)
}
```

(You may need to change all `count:`s or `capacity:`s having `2` in my code to `colors.count`.)

And then..

```
elementPtr.deinitialize(count: colors.count)
elementPtr.deallocate(capacity: colors.count)
fooPointer.deinitialize(count: colors.count)
fooPointer.deallocate(capacity: colors.count)
```

Anyway, match `initialize` and `deinitialize`, `allocate` and `deallocate`.

You may find some useful types in Swift Standard Library to improve the code, but too much thing at one time may not be a good habit to learn...

Comment: I have upvoted and accepted your answer, thank you so much! I understand this much better now. 

One quick follow up question. In that last line of code you wrote, how does that load(as:) function work? As far as I am concerned its just a void* pointer. How then can Swift possibly know how to read those raw bytes and  create the CountedColor object. I read the documentation and it still did not help. This seems like magic to me, honestly coming from the objC, C++, and C world, a lot of Swift interoperation with C seems like magic to me in general :(

Comment: @AyBayBay, _how does that load(as:) function work?_ you would cast a  `void *` to an appropriate type when retrieving some content in C, like `*((SomeType *)aVoidPointer)`. In Swift, `aVoidPointer.load(as: SomeType.self)` is its equivalent. Or you can think it as a shortcut form of `aVoidPointer.assumingMemoryBound(to: SomeType.self).pointee`.

Comment: Alright thank you very much :)
One last follow up question, I would like to review the objects I need to deallocate/free. Looking at the code I would imagine that would be the callbackPtr, every single UnsafeMutablePointer<CountColor> object I added to the BinaryHeap, and lastly elementPtr and the objects inside of it..

Is my understanding here correct?

Comment: Simply saying `initialize` and `deinitialize` needs to match, `allocate` and `deallocate` as well. And with actual code, it may be too long to be a comment, I'll append some example to my answer later.

Comment: Alright thank you ver much @OOPer
You have been of great help to something that stumped me all day. I guess my main question is just with the fooPointer, I use that and allocate 2 objects I throw into the data structure so I guess I need to store those in an array and deallocate those 2 CountedColors at some point as well. If that makes sense I think my understanding is good to go.

Comment: @AyBayBay, updated. Hope the appended part would help you understand better.